# Multiple Male Bettas in 200+ Gallon?

Tags: aquarium, fish, betta

I am not doing this, nor do I plan to (due to the aggressive nature of male bettas). But I was wondering if it would be possible to house multiple male bettas in a 200+ gallon tank?
I definitely imagine it would be a lot of work, and a lot of plants with hide spots. But is it doable?

Opinions?

Comment: WHEN they find each other they will fight.

Answer (score 2):

Since you say 200+ without upper limit, I will say **Yes** if the tank is big enough (I cannot provide a number unfortunately) to allow for a different, defendable territory for each betta. And like you say a lot of places to hide or swim away. Every betta has a different personality. Some of them might insist on killing the other one unfortunately.

It also matters which fish is introduced first. If a fish already decided that the whole aquarium is his, the new one has more chance to be bullied. Likely a newly-arrived betta might be more timid with fishes that are already at-home. It might be better to introduce both at the same time, with the lights closed. Don't leave the lights open for too long, you will reduce aggressivity like this.

Answer (score 0):

200+ gallons seems to approach a commercial-sized aquarium and at this point I think it would better to get in contact with an aquarium consulting company and ask them. There may be a better way.